# Using a class in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, class

When I'm developing a ConsoleApp there is no problem to use classes in my Main that I've created in separated files (Project Menu --> Add Class). But later, when I try to do it in WPF that class is not recognized. I have made sure that the namespace it's the same both in my "MainWindow.xaml.cs" and my Class Canal.cs. When I define that same class but *inside* MainWindow.xaml.cs everything works fine, but due to the extension of the code I prefer separate it.

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
//using      
 namespace Tcomp
    {
     public partial class MainWindow : Window
            {
        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                { //Stuff but I can't use class created outside of MainWindow.xaml.cs
}
}
}
```

Canal.cs

```
//using
    namespace TComp
    {
        public class Canal
        { //some propreties here
    }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: some code to explain that.

Comment: Please provide some to show how you are doing this in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Tcomp

namespace TComp
```

You know that C# is case-sensitive, right?

Answer (score -1):

Create the class inside a library project not on a console app. And on your WPF project, add a project reference to the library project you have created.

Comment: I've created the class inside the WPF project, the ConsoleApp was only to show that it works if I do it that way but not in WPF. Maybe it's because MainWindow.xaml.cs is inside MainWindow.xaml?

Comment: As I explained in my answer, you can put that properties within public partial class MainWindow; in this case you do not need to create additional classes/namespaces.

Comment: Maybe my ignorance makes me blind, but I still can't get it. Due to the extension of the code in my auxiliar class I want to be able to manage that code separated from the MainWindow (where I will be calling the created class outside).

Answer (score -1):

@mcxiand already answered your question. I would like to add another option: you can use a

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
```

and add it to as many files as you want containing your code, thus there will be no need to create additional class library. The key word here is `partial`, which allows the code encapsulated in this class to spread over multiple files (.cs).

Comment: I'm already using that sintaxis (default btw) and I've tried to put the word partial in myClass.cs but still can't use it inside MainWindow.xaml.cs

Comment: My intentions are to use the code created in the separated class file (.cs) in the MainWindow, it's kind like the opposite

Comment: OK, then add 'using TComp;' in order to access the properties/methods of its public classes.

Comment: This is a very bad approach. The Canal class doesn't have to know about Window. Not all classes are View classes.

Comment: Ok, I've fixed the problem, the issue was that I copied the code of the class from my ConsoleApp, and then I pasted it in a created class in my WPF Program. Something internally went wrong and I couldn't acess the class. After creating an entire new project and including the code carefully finally I succeed. Thanks everybody for the help.

Answer (score -1):

You must either instantiate the Canal class:

```
var myClass = new Canal();
```

and then you can use the properties from it. Make myClass a private member of your MainWindow.xaml.cs and you can access it anytime. Or the second way, make Canal class static and then you can access it from everywhere. Hope this helps.